# Count the number of rows with values between two dates, in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a DataFrame where the columns are stages in a process, and every row has dates of when that record entered into each "stage." I want to count for each column the number of rows that have a date inside a certain range. Then, the end goal is to plot something that looks like a funnel to see the drop off between stages, and compare funnels between date ranges. An example table is below.

#### Input Table

|  | stage 1 | stage 2 | stage 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| row 1 | 1/3/2023 | 4/3/2023 | 5/7/2023 |
| row 2 | 2/5/2023 | 2/6/2023 | 3/4/2023 |
| row 3 | 1/15/2023 | 6/3/2023 | 7/8/2023 |

#### Desired Output Table

|  | stage 1 | stage 2 | stage 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2023 - 4/1/2023 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 4/1/2023 - 7/1/2023 | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| 7/1/2023 - 10/1/2023 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

At first my approach was to just select all rows with dates in the range with something like:

```py
start = pd.to_datetime('2023-1-1')
end = pd.to_datetime('2023-3-30')
df[(df[list_of_cols] >= start).any(axis=1)) & (df[list_of_columns] <= end).any(axis=1))]
df[list_of_cols].count()
```

but in the case of the example above, that would return and count row 3 in all 3 stages even though stages 2 and 3 happened outside of the date range.

So the code that I have now is a function that will take a DataFrame similar to the input table example, and a list of dates, and return a DataFrame with the count of each column between each of the dates in the list.

```py
def funnel_by_time(df: pd.DataFrame, dates: list):
    df_dict = {date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'): [] for date in dates[:-1]}
    # make a dict for each row, with its' the count in each column
    for i in range(len(dates)-1):
        date_range = pd.date_range(dates[i], dates[i+1])
        
        # append the count into its' row's list
        for col in stage_cols:
            df_dict[dates[i].strftime('%m/%d/%Y')].append(
                df[col].isin(date_range).sum())
    return pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_dict,
                                  orient='index',
                                  columns=stage_cols)
```

This gets the desired output, but I'm just wondering, is there an easier way that isn't as much of a hack method?

Comment: Can you provide the exact expected output for clarity?

Comment: @mozway I've edited the question to include the desired output table, along with the function that I made to produce that output.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you compute the boolean and (`&`) after aggregation with `any`, and you shouldn't use `any` if you plan to count.

You should first check for all date if they are between start and end, then aggregate:

```
start = pd.to_datetime('2023-1-1')
end = pd.to_datetime('2023-3-30')

tmp = df.apply(pd.to_datetime)
df.loc['count'] = (tmp.ge(start) & tmp.le(end)).sum()
```

Output:

```
         stage 1   stage 2   stage 3
row 1   1/3/2023  4/3/2023  5/7/2023
row 2   2/5/2023  2/6/2023  3/4/2023 
row 3  1/15/2023  6/3/2023  7/8/2023
count          3         1         1
```

Intermediates:

```
# tmp
         stage 1    stage 2    stage 3
row 1 2023-01-03 2023-04-03 2023-05-07
row 2 2023-02-05 2023-02-06 2023-03-04
row 3 2023-01-15 2023-06-03 2023-07-08

# tmp.ge(start)
       stage 1  stage 2  stage 3
row 1     True     True     True
row 2     True     True     True
row 3     True     True     True

# tmp.le(end)
       stage 1  stage 2  stage 3
row 1     True    False    False
row 2     True     True     True
row 3     True    False    False

# tmp.ge(start) & tmp.le(end)
       stage 1  stage 2  stage 3
row 1     True    False    False
row 2     True     True     True
row 3     True    False    False
```